# Query Activity in ExactTarget - getting date out of datetime

Tags: marketing-cloud, datetime, date

Using ExactTarget queries to retrieve data, i found that the regular 'Date' function that should extract only the date, without time from a column, is not working.
Is there any workaround or something i can do to get only the date?

the SQL code example:

```
SELECT O.EVENTDATE FROM _OPEN
```

this query will bring the result of `2014-01-01 08:00 AM`
what i want to see is '2014-01-01'
what i did in regular MYSQL client is just addid `date(`) before the `O.EVENTDATE` and it worked, but it is not working in ET internal query call.

Thanks!

Comment: Do you have any code available to help us understand exactly what you are doing?

Comment: very easy - i need to extract the date only from a table, and not the time., for example:     select eventdate from _sent    will result in date+time, i want to see the date only. in a regular mysqsl client adding the 'date' function did that but in exacttarget internal query this function doesn't work..

Answer (score 2):

SQL Server 2008 (ET uses SQL Server) has a date type with no time, to which you could convert.  Use something like

```
SELECT CONVERT(date, getdate()) AS testDate
```

for your query

----UPDATE----

Based on the additional query added, I would do

```
SELECT CONVERT(date, O.EVENTDATE) AS someDate FROM _Open O
```

Comment: Wrote it like that:   SELECT CONVERT(date , getdate(j.pickuptime)) AS job_time     but than got this error message: "The getdate function requires 0 argument(s)."

Comment: @kfir please update your question with the code example and error message. For more information, be sure to review the [how to ask a good question doc](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/how-to-ask)

Comment: What is j.pickuptime?  A datetime?  Then the query would be   SELECT CONVERT(date , j.pickuptime)

Comment: Thanks! worked but needed also to change the data extension from 'Date' to 'Text'. Thanks a lot!